# SSIS - Split flat file in ole db destination

Tags: ssis

I have to fill a table from a csv file but with a different order.
Csv file is like this:  a;b;c;1;2;3;4
and table should be like this:

> ```
> a b c 1 2
> a b c 3 4
> ```

How is that possible?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not clear what you need, or what problems you're having. Can you expand a bit more? Perhaps an example row from the CSV file with actual data, and a corresponding example of how you want the destination table to look? And what problems you're having getting there?

Comment: You can use a cross join to turn one row into two, then you can just use case statements to transpose the columns. I could pose a solution but I'm guessing bet you will either not return to the question or we will discover that the real question is much more complicated.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please provide your source file structure and destination table structure with some sample rows. Seems like you can use copy column to have first three columns and rest can be splitted.